# Matlab: How can I call object properties using a string?

Tags: matlab, object, dynamic, matrix

I am currently working on a data analysis program that contains two objects: `Experiment` and `RunSummary`. The `Experiment` object contains multiple instances of the `RunSummary` object. Each `RunSummary` object contains multiple properties (row matrices) each containing different data points for a given run.

For example: `Experiment.RunSummary(5).Tmean` is row matrix containing all of the average torque values for run 5 in my experiment.

I am currently trying to find a way to combine selected common properties from specific runs into a single matrix that can be used for further analysis. The current way I have had to do this is:

```
X(:,1) = [Drilling.Runs(1).Tmean,...
             Drilling.Runs(2).Tmean,...
                 Drilling.Runs(3).Tmean,...
                     Drilling.Runs(5).Tmean]';

X(:,2) = [Drilling.Runs(1).Fmean,...
             Drilling.Runs(2).Fmean,...
                 Drilling.Runs(3).Fmean,...
                     Drilling.Runs(5).Fmean]';
```

This code takes the average torque (Tmean) and average force (Fmean) from runs 1, 2, 3, and 5 and combines them in a single matrix, X, with Tmean for all runs in the first column and Fmean in the second. Although this method works, I have over 20 different properties and 15 different runs making this coding very tedious.

I have tried using code such as `get(Experiment.RunSummary(i),'Tmean')` to try and retrieve these property matricies, but was met with the error:

> Conversion to double from RunSummary is not possible.

- Is there a way to easily combine all of these different properties
  into a single matrix using strings to determine which properties are used?

Thanks,
  metro

Edit: Drilling is the name of the Experiment object. Runs is the name of the RunSummary object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [dynamic fields](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html).  The documentation is for structs, but the same principal works for classes (at least on my R2012a install).
You can also use the comma-separate nature of object array indexing to compress the code.
Example:

```
I      = [1,2,3,5]              ;
props  = {'Tmean','Fmean'}      ;
Nprops = length(props)          ;
X      = zeros(length(I),Nprops);

for k = 1:Nprops 
    X(:,k) = [Drilling.Runs(I).(props{k})]';
end
```

Comment: That worked! I had to change `X = zeros(length(I),Nprops);` to `X = zeros(length([Drilling.Runs(I).HoleNums]),props);` to get it to the right size, but the dynamic fields worked great. Thank you!